# how to fill a div with an image the user uploads?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a rudimentary site that enables users to upload images to the server and download them from it. I want to add a "preview" feature that will allow the user to see its photo beforehand. Here is my code:

```html
 <div class="container">
        <input type="file" class="title3" id="picker"/>
        <img src= this.input alt="IDK why, but I can't display that." class="title3">;
```

Comment: you need to upload the file to your server first.  Then provide the location in the img tag.  What language are you using server side?

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript to dynamically update the image source of the `img` tag.

```js
const img = document.getElementById('preview');
const input = document.getElementById('picker');
input.onchange = function(ev) {
  const file = ev.target.files[0]; // get the file
  const blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  img.src = blobURL;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="file" class="title3" id="picker" />
  <img id="preview" alt="IDK why, but I can't display that." class="title3" width="200">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated the code.

```js
const selectFile = evt => {
  const [file] = evt.target.files;
  if (file) {
    document.getElementById('preview').src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="file" class="title3" id="picker" onchange="selectFile(event)" />
  <img id="preview" alt="IDK why, but I can't display that." class="image">;
</div>
```

Comment: Ended up using this snippet in my project, thanks!